# Swift unexpected error Cannot assign to '' in 'self'

Tags: ios, swift

I have a colours array and I am trying to get a random colour from it without getting the same two colours in a row and came across an error for `previousNumber = randomNumber` saying Cannot assign to 'previousNumber' in 'self'

```
var previousNumber: UInt32?

    func generateRandomNumber() -> Int {
        var coloursArrayLength = UInt32(coloursArray.count)
        var randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(coloursArrayLength)
        while previousNumber == randomNumber {
            randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(coloursArrayLength)
        }
        previousNumber = randomNumber
        var randomNumberInt = Int(randomNumber)
        return randomNumberInt
    }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your code works for me in a playground. We might need more context. (Also, you might want to consider using a `do ... while` loop instead of a `while` there, which will save the need to repeat the code that calls arc4random_uniform.)

Comment: The only way I can reproduce your error is if I use `let` to declare `previousNumber` rather than `var`. Are you sure this is your exact code?

Answer (score 7):

I am guessing your function is actually inside a struct not shown in the code snippet, and the problem is you haven’t declared the function as `mutating` (i.e. the function can only be called on structs declared with `let` not `var` because it mutates self).

I’d also suggest breaking out the logic for generating the random number into a separate function for clarity and also to cut down on needing `var` so much:

```
func generateRandom(#upTo: UInt32, #notRepeatOf: UInt32?) -> UInt32 {
    // bear in mind though that you might need to handle if your coloursArray has one entry...
    precondition(upTo > 1 || notRepeatOf == nil , "avoid infinite loop")
    while true {
        let candidate = arc4random_uniform(upTo)
        if candidate != notRepeatOf { return candidate }
    }
}

struct S {
    var previousNumber: UInt32? = nil
    let coloursArray = [1,2,3,4]

    // note mutating keyword, fixes the "cannot
    // assign to self.previousNumber" error
    mutating func generateRandomNumber() -> Int {
        let newNumber = generateRandom(upTo: UInt32(coloursArray.count), notRepeatOf: previousNumber)
        previousNumber = newNumber
        return Int(newNumber)
    }
}

// if you declare the struct with let,
let a = S()
// it won’t let you call mutating funcs
// "Immutable value of type 'S' only has mutating members named 'generateRandomNumber'"
a.generateRandomNumber()

// have to declare with var
var b = S()
b.generateRandomNumber()
```